# Manipulate Excel file on Sharepoint using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, sharepoint, onedrive

I have a SharePoint system with authentication automatic.

So, I need to read, create, edit some Excel files from this Sharepoint.

No, I don't want download it and manipulate in local. I need to read like a Dataframe and save like a Excel at the end.

The functions read_excel and to_excel from Pandas, they don't recognize the URL address.

I can use like a Windows path if I use a Sharepoint path with origin in my computer (like OneDrive), but the others can't run the same routines, because they need use this URL address.

Answer (score 2):

You should try using this module: [Office365-REST-Python-Client](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client). You can do everything you asked for using this.

Comment: I don't see how use this. All the examples that I found, it was about authentication, and I don't need this.

Comment: Why not? you can download files, update them and upload them back! Wasn't that your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can synchronize your Sharepoint with your computer.

In that way, you can access Sharepoint files through Python with an absolute path "C:\Users\user_name\Documents...", make your edits and the files will be synchronized with the online Sharepoint.

If others need to use your routine, you can make the path dynamic:

```
import getpass
import os

user_name = getpass.getuser()
base_path = r"C:\Users"
sharepoint_path = os.path.join(base_path, user_name, sharepoint_folder, subfolder1, ...)
```